# MySQL attempting to delete all rows which are not constrained by foreign key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, sql-delete

Okay, this is (probably) a **very** simple question, but I am afraid I know almost no MySQL, so please put up with me. I'm just trying to delete every row from one table which is not constrained by a Foreign Key in another table - a specific table, there are only two tables involved here. The create statements look a bit like:

```
CREATE TABLE  `testschema`.`job` (
  `Job_Id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Comment` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Job_Id`) USING BTREE,
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE  `ermieimporttest`.`jobassignment` (
  `JobAssignment_Id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `JobId` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`JobAssignment_Id`),
  KEY `FK_jobassignment_1` (`JobId`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_jobassignment_1` FOREIGN KEY (`JobId`) REFERENCES `job` (`Job_Id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Any my SQL statement is:

```
DELETE FROM job USING job INNER JOIN jobAssignment WHERE job.Job_Id != jobAssignment.JobId;
```

I thought this was correct - it should delete every job from the job table for which there does not exist a job assignment which has that job as it's Foreign Key. However, this fails with the following error when I try and execute it:

> Cannot delete or update a parent row:
>   a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`testdatabase`.`jobassignment`,
>   CONSTRAINT `FK_jobassignment_1`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`JobId`) REFERENCES `job`
>   (`Job_Id`))

So what silly thing am I doing wrong?

EDIT: As usual, I found an answer only seconds after posting here. I used the (completely different) query:

```
DELETE FROM job WHERE Job_Id NOT IN (SELECT JobId FROM jobassignment)
```

Out of curiosity, is this the better way to do it? Was my original idea even feasible? And if so, what was wrong with it?

Comment: In your statement dependend subquery is executed for each row in a job table, so it's very inefficient.

Comment: Your posted `DELETE` statement appears to be a bit muddled up, but to answer your curiosity: for every row in `job`, your `JOIN` is producing a list of rows for every row in `jobassignment` which has an id not equal to the job id. To see this more clearly, turn your `DELETE` statement into a `SELECT` statement. Something like this: `SELECT * FROM job INNER JOIN jobassignment ON job.Job_Id != jobassignment.JobId;`

Comment: Thanks Mike. I see what you mean now - my statement as it was created a cross-product of the two tables, minus the rows where Job_Id == JobId. Trying to delete this then of course fails, because it includes Jobs which are constrained. Cheers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM job USING job 
LEFT JOIN jobAssignment ON(job.Job_Id = jobAssignment.JobId)
WHERE jobAssignment.JobId IS NULL;
```

Comment: I choose this as the answer because it is the answer to my question of how to do the delete using a join. Although I did actually use Jaymz's answer, I found it indepedently of using it here, so while I give my graditude to him, this is the closer answer to my final question. Thanks, Naktibalda.

Answer (score 5):

You'll probably need a subquery, not sure if this will work in mySQL, but something similar at least:

```
DELETE FROM job
WHERE job.Job_Id NOT IN (
  SELECT JobId FROM jobAssignment
)
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm afraid I choose Naktibalda's answer for the 'correct' answer because it answered my edited question the closest, but this solution was the one I actually found and used first! Thanks Jaymz.

Answer (score 1):

Naktibalda suggests the subquery may be inefficient; if so you could try

```
DELETE FROM job
     WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                           FROM jobassignment
                           WHERE job.Job_Id = jobassignment.Job_Id);
```

I've had bad experiences with IN and NOT IN in the past; less trouble with NOT EXISTS.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - the subquery approach did run in < 1 second (at least, I think - at the most it wasn't a noticeable pause) for 6500 rows, but I know that when it comes to databases there can be alot more rows than that quite easily!